# sum ofevery n-th rows and n-th columns of a data frame

Tags: r

I have a large data frame  3000 columns and 3000 rows and I need to sum every 5 rows and then every 5 columns and convert my data frame into 600 rows and 600 columns: 
my data is like this

```
 matches1 matches2 matches3 matches4 matches5 ... 
    1        0        1        0        1            
    0        1        0        0        1            
    0        1        0        1        0
    1        0        1        0        1
    0        1        1        1        1
```

my expected results are this:
my data is like this for the first 5 rows and 5columns is this:

```
  w1 ... w600
  14
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create an index for aggregating rows and columns using `gl()` and then use `aggregate` and `split.default` to sum rows and columns respectively.

```
index <- gl(nrow(df)/5, 5)

#Sum rows
df1 <- aggregate(.~index, df, sum)[-1]

#Sum columns
sapply(split.default(df1, index), rowSums)
```

Comment: Why do we need to sum columns with  `rowSums`?

Answer (score 0):

We can create a grouping index with `%/%`

```
index <- (seq_len(nrow(df)) - 1) %/% 5 + 1
```

Then, use that in `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~ index, df, sum)[-1]
```

Or in `rowsum`

```
rowsum(df, group = index)
```

---

It can also be used for summing the columns

```
sapply(split.default(df, index), rowSums)
```